# How to sync Google Calendar from Galaxy S3 to Web Calendar

Tags: synchronization, google-calendar-api

Can anyone tell me how to sync Google Calendar from Galaxy S3 to Google Web Calendar - it works from Google Web Calendar to Galaxy S3 device but not other way round.

Comment: Nope, but I bet they can over on the sister-site http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5):

I got this off another forum and it worked for me:

Do this and it should work.

```
settings > account and sync > uncheck background sync (OFF)
```

then go to :

```
settings > applications > manage applications
```

find contacts storage, select it and CLEAR DATA

Then go back to accounts and sync and check background sync (ON)

Then select your gmail account and check contacts and then reboot. Wait 5-10 min and you'll see the contacts start to appear.

Answer (score 0):

My wife just had that exact issue with her Sensation.
Open your g-mail-
open calendar- 
open calendar settings-
open mobile set-up- enter phone# and follow the prompts and you should receive a conformation text. This worked for her and we certainly hope this works for you. Hope you're having a Great Day where ever you are in the World :)
Sincerely,
 San Diego